# What is the runtime of this algorithm? (Recursive Pascal's triangle)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

Given the following function:

```
Function f(n,m)
   if n == 0 or m == 0: return 1
   return f(n-1, m) + f(n, m-1)
```

What's the runtime compexity of `f`? I understand how to do it quick and dirty, but how to properly characterize it? Is it `O(2^(m*n))`?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't 2^(m+n)?

Comment: @mbeckish can't be, if `m=0` or `n=0`, there will be no recursion calls, no matter what's the value of the other variable

Comment: @RonTeller - Big O notation ignores constants, so if the runtime is actually 2^(m+n) +1 or something like that, in Big O it is still O(2^(m+n)).

Comment: @mbeckish I'm not talking about constants. let's assume `m=0`, you are claiming the running time should be `O(2^n)`, which it isn't.

Comment: @RonTeller - You're right.  blubb got the right answer.

Comment: Is the height of your binary tree equivalent to m*n ?,I agree @mbeckish comment.

Comment: @amink - I think it is only a complete binary tree to a depth of min(m,n).  After that, the tree gets more sparse.  The longest branches would be length m + n.

Comment: This link here may answer your question:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80582/solving-recursion-with-2-parameters

Answer (score 6):

This is an instance of Pascal's triangle: every element is the sum of the two elements just above it, the sides being all ones.

So `f(n, m) = (n + m)! / (n! . m!)`.

Now to know the number of calls to `f` required to compute `f(n, m)`, you can construct a modified Pascal's triangle: instead of the sum of the elements above, consider `1 + sum` (the call itself plus the two recursive calls).

Draw the modified triangle and you will quickly convince yourself that this is exactly `2.f(n, m) - 1`.

You can obtain the asymptotic behavior of the binomial coefficients from Stirling's approximation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas

```
f(n, m) ~ (n + m)^(n + m) / (n^n . m^m)
```

Answer (score 5):

The runtime of `f(n, m)` is in `O(f(n, m))`. This is easily verified by the following observation:

```
Function g(n, m):
    if n=0 or m=0: return 1
    return g(n-1, m) + g(n, m-1) + 1
```

The function `f` is called equally often as `g`. Furthermore, the function `g` is called exactly `g(n, m)` times to evaluate the result of `g(n, m)`. Likewise, the function `f` is called exactly `g(n, m) = 2*f(n, m)-1` times in order to evaluate the result of `f(n, m)`.

As @Yves Daoust points out in his answer, `f(n, m) = (n + m)!/(n!*m!)`, therefore you get a non-recursive runtime of `O((n+m)!/(n!*m!))` for `f`.

Comment: Not sure about the second part: let's assume `n=10 m=1`, your function returns `2` (which should be `2*f`), while the original function would return `11`.

Comment: Now it would return `3`, which is still off

Comment: @RonTeller: I revised my answer. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

### Understanding the Recursive Function

```
f(n, 0) = 1
f(0, m) = 1
f(n, m) = f(n - 1, m) + f(n, m - 1)
```

The values look like a [Pascal triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) to me:

```
   n 0  1  2  3  4 ..
 m

 0   1  1  1  1  1 ..
 1   1  2  3  4
 2   1  3  6
 3   1  4     .
 4   1           .
 .   .
 .   .
```

### Solving the Recursion Equation

The values of Pascal's triangle can be expressed as [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). Translating the coordinates one gets the solution for f:

```
f(n, m) = (n + m) 
          (  m  )
        = (n + m)! / (m! (n + m - m)!) 
        = (n + m)! / (n! m!)
```

which is a nice term symmetric in both arguments n and m. (Final term first given by @Yves Daoust in this discussion)

### Pascal's Rule

The recursion equation of f can be derived by using the symmetry of the binomial coefficients and [Pascal's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)

```
f(n, m) = (n + m)
          (  n  )
        = (n + m)
          (  m  )
        = ((n + m) - 1) + ((n + m) - 1)
          (      m    )   (    m - 1  )
        = ((n - 1) + m) + (n + (m - 1))
          (     m     )   (    m      )
        = f(n - 1, m) + f(n, m - 1)
```

### Determing the Number of Calls

The "number of calls of f" calculation function F is similar to f, we just have to add the call to f itself and the two recursive calls:

```
F(0, m) = F(n, 0) = 1, otherwise

F(n, m) = 1 + F(n - 1, m) + F(n, m - 1)
```

(Given first by @blubb in this discussion).

### Understanding the Number of Calls Function

If we write it down, we get another triangle scheme:

```
 1  1  1  1  1 ..
 1  3  5  7
 1  5 11
 1  7     .
 1           .
 .
 .
```

Comparing the triangles value by value, one guesses

```
F(n, m) = 2 f(n, m) - 1  (*)
```

(Result first suggested by @blubb in this discussion)

### Proof

We get

```
F(0, m) = 2 f(0, m) - 1  ; using (*)
        = 1              ; yields boundary condition for F 

F(n, 0) = 2 f(n, 0) - 1 
        = 1
```

as it should and examining the otherwise clause, we see that

```
F(n, m) = 2 f(n, m) - 1                                   ; assumption
        = 2 ( f(n - 1, m) + f(n, m - 1) ) - 1             ; definition f
        = 1 + (2 f(n - 1, m) - 1) + (2 f(n, m - 1) - 1)   ; algebra
        = 1 + F(n - 1, m) + F(n, m - 1)                   ; 2 * assumption
```

Thus if we use (*) and the otherwise clause for f, the otherwise clause for F results.

As the finite difference equation and the start condition for F hold, we know it is F (uniqueness of the solution).

### Estimating the Asymptotic Behaviour of the Number of Calls

Now on calculating / estimating the values of F (i.e. the runtime of your algorithm).

As

```
F = 2 f - 1
```

we see that

```
O(F) = O(f).
```

So the runtime of this algorithm is

```
O( (n + m)! / (n! m!) )
```

(Result first given by @Yves Daoust in this discussion)

### Approximating the Runtime

Using the [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

```
n! ~= sqrt(2 pi n) (n / e)^n
```

one can get a form without hard to calculate factorials. One gets

```
f(n, m) ~= 1/(2 pi) sqrt((n+m) / (n m)) [(n + m)^(n + m)] / (n^n m^m)
```

thus arriving at

```
O( sqrt((n + m) / (n m)) [(n + m)^(n + m)] / (n^n m^m) )
```

(Use of Stirling's formula first suggested by @Yves Daoust in this discussion)